# Slick Slider Dots & Arrows Are Not Showing

Tags: css, sass, slick.js

On this site, https://kkmpr.com/, there is a section that says "Shop" and below it there is a Slider built using slick slider. I know how to change the dot and arrow colors (on the :before), but even in my inspector, I can't get the colors to change. At first, I thought maybe they were being positioned underneath the slider images, but I don't think that is the case either. I can't figure out what is going on. If I disable the slick-theme.scss style sheet, I can see the unstyled "Next" and "Previous" buttons with the numbers for the dots below.

Comment: Minimal code you find would be helpful for us to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like there is `overflow: hidden` applied to `.slider`, and the arrows are absolutely positioned outside of that element.

Adding the following CSS reveals the arrows in the Shop section:

```
#slider-container .slider {
    overflow: initial;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Enabling the arrows and dots are properties of the object.

They probably have them disabled in the properties of the actual js object.